# aerogear - how to send a push notification to one user

Tags: cordova, jboss, aerogear

I have a client-server service. The client runs on apache cordova and the server is java based. I need to add push notifications to it and I thought about using aerogear. I read the tutorials and successfully sent a push notification from the cordova app.

I want to be able to send a push notification to just one of the clients. Can this be done using aerogear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to do it would be to add some "criteria" to the message you are sending that targets a specific installation.

So during the registration of your device with the Unified Push Server, you can add an alias to the push config, the device token would probably be best:

`var pushConfig = {
    pushServerURL: "<pushServerURL e.g http(s)//host:port/context >",
    alias: "<alias e.g. a username or an email address optional>",
    android: {
      ...
    },
    ios: {
     ...
    }
};`

Then when you send your message, you can add that "alias" as a "criteria".

edit:  i've created this JIRA, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AGPUSH-1117 , to track this

Comment: For newer versions of Aerogear:

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Aerogear (curl script example):

curl -u "{PushApplicationID}:{MasterSecret}"
      -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" 
      -X POST
      -d '{
          **"criteria":** {
            "variants" : ["c3f0a94f-48de-4b77-a08e-68114460857e", "444939cd-ae63-4ce1-96a4-de74b77e3737" ....],
            **"alias"** : ["user@account.com", "someone@aerogear.org", ....],
            "categories" : ["someCategory", "otherCategory"],
            "deviceType" : ["iPad", "AndroidTablet"]
          },
       "message": {
         "alert":"HELLO!",
         "sound":"default",
         "badge":7,
         "content-available" : true,
         "action-category" : "some_category",
         "simple-push": "version=123",
         "user-data": {
            "someKey":"some value",
            "anotherCustomKey":"some other value"
         },
         "windows": {
            "type": "tile",
            "duration": "short",
            "badge": "alert",
            "tileType": "TileWideBlockAndText01",
            "images": ["Assets/test.jpg", "Assets/background.png"], 
            "textFields": ["foreground text"]
          },
       },
       "config": {
         "ttl" : 3600,
       }
     }'

https://SERVER:PORT/CONTEXT/rest/sender